# pass a number to external js file using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to pass a value from input by a user to a java script file using add Event listener  .. I have HTML

```js
var x = document.getElementById("btn");
x.addEventListener("click", resolve);
var y = document.getElementById("x").value;
console.log(x);
console.log(y);

function resolve() {
  if (y >= 20000) {

    alert("yes greater than 20000");
  } else {

    alert("nnn oo good");
  }
}
```

```html
<label><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{5}" maxlength="5" id="x"/>
    </label>
<button type="submit" id="btn"> Hit!</button>

<script src="functions.js"></script>
```

file but the java script file is not getting the value

Comment: You need to put `var y = ...` ` inside the `resolve` function. As it is you only assign it once, when the page is first loaded, and don't check its current value when the click event happens.

Comment: .value does not automatically update

Comment: here is the html code

Comment: <label><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{5}" maxlength="5" id="x"/>
</label>
<button type="submit" id="btn"> Hit!</button>

<script src="functions.js"></script>

</script>